# How to add custom POIs to google maps navigation

Tags: google-maps

I am a happy user of Android system and constantly using Google Maps Navigation (betta). So far you can add layers with different POIs (shops, banks, gas stations, etc.) on the map while drive. My question is if there is an API exist to add your own layer (with your customized POIs) to be displayed in [Google Map Navigation](http://www.google.com/mobile/navigation/) (not just google map) while you drive or walk.

Thanks in advance.